# What did I try to do to you?

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, steganography

> Do
>   you
>   keep toothpaste in a
>   tube?
>   Can you *even* decipher the code below?
>   v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

**What did I try to do to you?**
Bonus question: **Did I succeed?**

Comment: This puzzle didn't let me down.

Comment: No, you did not succeed. People have tried this on me so many times that I recognize that code anywhere

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there really isn't much contained here that I would describe as a puzzle...

Comment: @Alconja This is not a difficult puzzle, but I believe it is still a puzzle - you have to link some parts of it to get to the solution and there are clues on how to do it. It just has another meaning additionally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You tried to

> Rickroll me

and

> You did not succeed :P

Answer (score 6):

**What did I try to do to you?**

> You obvious tried to make me feel horrible for being so bad at these kinds of puzzles and make me cry in shame.

**Did I succeed?**

> Yes... yes you did...

**EDIT**

> Unless....
>  v=dQw4w9WgXcQ  looks like a url ending.
>  Also I can see that there is the word **you** and **tube** in the puzzle
>  And by the question and the bonus I get the creepy feeling you are trying to rickroll us... so I will not proceed further with this puzzle so that I can say **NO** to your bonus question! HA!

Comment: Am I correct to say this was the earliest correct answer? I see the "EDIT" stuff, but I don't see the "revision history" which suggests it is the first one indeed (or I don't understand PSE mechanisms yet).

Comment: @oleslaw I don't know for sure. There was still no other answers when I started my edit for sure. But after my edit the answers started pouring in real fast. If someone claim they finished their answer before I finish my edit, they can get the chosen answer.

Comment: I would be curious to know why my edit history is not displaying too.... Maybe when the edit is within 1 minute of the post it doesn't count as an edit or something like that?

Comment: Unless anyone can proove me wrong, I accept this answer as the quickest one.

Comment: It was the quickest answer, but the correct answer was first postet by Levieux, his answer was already here when i finished typing mine, so i feel like he shoud get marked as correct. The edit was made after both Levieux and me posted the correct answer.

Comment: @Timme Thanks for explaining the chronology.

Comment: @stackreader There is a "grace period" after an edit/post, where any subsequent edits are rolled into the same revision.  This prevents edit histories from getting extremely long when there are a number of minor edits in short succession.

Comment: @oleslaw Hover over the time text above the user (currently "7 hours ago") to see time down to the second.  This post is from `2016-11-17 08:37:34Z`

Comment: Thanks @GentlePurpleRain. So there is no way to know what time my edit was done anymore is there? Gone into the abyss of 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 4):

I knew it, but I had to see anyway

> [image]

So due to my curiosity you

> Did indeed succeed in rickrolling me

Answer (score 2):

You

> Tried to Rick Roll me.

That's because:

> If you take all the *even* lines and you add ?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ to a you tube address, you get: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ, wich well, you can check out for yourself to know if it succeeded.

Comment: You wrote "first and third" where I think you meant "second and fourth".  Note that "sixth" is also significant (see italicized word in puzzle).

Comment: @mathmandan yeah, thanks for letting me know. I don't get what "*even* " has to do with youtube though, do you mind explaining?

Comment: @Timme The lines you added are actually 2nd, 4th and 6th line which are the even ones.

Comment: now i see it.. yeah.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to:

> Rickroll me

You:

> Succeeded rickrolling me in 2016

Comment: this has already been answered